# Is there a relationship between the alpha of fat tails and kurtosis

Tags: kurtosis, power-law

From Wikipedia I have the compliment of the CDF parameterized for fat-tails distributions.

$$
\Pr[X>x] \sim x^{- \alpha}\text{ as }x \to \infty,\qquad \alpha > 0.\
$$

In forecasting literature a conservative heuristic is to manage variables with $\alpha \leq 2.5$ as practically unpredictable.

Distributions that have power law behavior are often only having this behavior for a limited range.

I was wondering if there was a relationship between **kurtosis** and **$\alpha$**. My hope would be to have a more fool proof kurtosis based heuristic as opposed to relying on the power law.

Comment: When $\alpha \le 4,$ the kurtosis must be infinite.  That's all one can say in this generality.  Assuming $X$ is bounded below, when $\alpha \gt 4$ the kurtosis (and, of course, all lower moments) will be defined and finite.